# SwiftUI - When I create multiplatform app, how to change view in scene?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, multiplatform

I am trying to create a multi-platform app from SwiftUI.

Here is my code in in

```
@main
struct MyApp: App
```

```
@State var sceneManager = SceneManager.shared
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            
            if sceneManager.state == .landing {
                
                LandingPageView()
            } else if sceneManager.state == .historyRecord {
                
                HistoryRecordView()
            }
        }
    }
```

when my login did success, I will change SceneManager.shared property, from `.landing` to `.historyRecord`

but the view didn't change, how should I change root view of scene?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SwiftUI 2.0** introduced `StateObject` for such purpose, so go with the following pattern

```
@StateObject var sceneManager = SceneManager.shared
```

and make

```
class SceneManager: ObservableObject {
   @Published var state: StateTypeHere
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, now I can change view by state.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `SceneManager` an `ObservableObject` and change the `@State` wrapper to `@ObservedObject`.

Make sure `state` is an `@Published` variable.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject

Or you can change your `@State` to `@State var sceneManagerState = SceneManager.shared.state`

Comment: Thanks, I already change my SceneManager to @ObservableObject
```

class SceneManager: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = SceneManager()
    
    @Published var state: SceneState = .landing
    
    private init() {}
}

```

Comment: Then just switch your `@State` wrapper to `@ObservedObject` for iOS 13+ or `@StateObject` for iOS 14+. `@State` is an internal wrapper specific to one `View`